# Определение блока при поиске через RegExp

Tags: jquery

```js
var InputSort = $('input#sort');
var minlen = 2;

InputSort.bind('keyup',function(){
    if(InputSort.val().length>=minlen) {
        dosearch();
    }
});

function dosearch() {
    var term = InputSort.val();
    $('.light').each(function(){
        $(this).after($(this).html()).remove();  
    });
    t = '';
    $('.sorting li').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(term, 'ig'), '<span class="light">$&</span>'));
    });
};
```

```css
ul {padding: 5px;}
li {list-style: none; color: #333;}
.light {color: #f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" id="sort">
<ul class="sorting">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Апельсин</li>
    <li>Лимон</li>
    <li>Дыня</li>
    <li>Арбуз</li>
</ul>
```

В данный момент этот код ищет совпадения в словах и выделяет их.
Как реализовать, что выделение будет идти на `<li>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const InputSort = document.getElementById('sort');
const minlen = 2;

InputSort.addEventListener('keyup', dosearch);

function dosearch() {
    const term = InputSort.value.toLowerCase();
    if(term.length < minlen) return true;
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.sorting li')].forEach(li => {
        if(li.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(term)) li.classList.add('light');
        else li.classList.remove('light');
    });
};
```

```css
ul {padding: 5px;}
li {list-style: none; color: #333;}
.light {color: #f00;}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Поиск" id="sort">
<ul class="sorting">
    <li>Яблоко</li>
    <li>Апельсин</li>
    <li>Лимон</li>
    <li>Дыня</li>
    <li>Арбуз</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: метка только jquery, зачем же писать ответ на чистом js ?

Comment: @teran Зачем писать на jQuery то, что можно написать на том, на чем написана jQuery?

Comment: с такой логикой любые js библиотеки не должны использоваться, ибо все это написано на js. А любые языки надо заменить на ассемблер.

Comment: @teran С вашей логикой в магазин без купюросчетной машины ходить нельзя. Библиотеки должны использоватся там, где это нужно. А jQuery нужен только для одного - чтобы студент Вася мог заработать тысячу рублей, скачав плагин в интернете и поставив его на сайт Николаю Георгиевичу. Ну и еще для ряда занимательных вещей - чтоб сайт работал медленнее, чтоб было побольше багов, чтоб весило всё это побольше, и в конечном итоге - чтоб юзеры почаще страдали.

Comment: ваше мнение по поводу использования jquery при разработке в данном контексте не важно. Важно то, что автор вопроса спрашивал про реализацию на jquery. На вопросы по пхп, вы отвечаете кодом на c++ ? 
Да он в целом может переписать js на jquery для практики. Но с другой стороны, качественный ответ с использованием библиотеки тоже поможет ему лучше изучить и сам язык и функциональность как языка так и библиотек.

Comment: @teran есть один маленький нюанс - код на js будет работать на сайте, к которому подлючена jquery. И даже на сайте, к которому она не подключена - можно просто copypaste и всё заработает. А вот код на с++ интерпретатор php не поймет.. Функциональность jQuery имело смысл изучать лет 10 назад, когда js был недоразвит и имел проблемы с кроссбраузерностью. И где же ваш ответ?

Comment: Давайте я оберну свой ответ в `$(function(){   })` и вы успокоитесь)

Comment: Если можно, напишите пожалуйста это на JQ.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, вы используете код

```
$('.sorting li').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(term, 'ig'), '<span class="light">$&</span>'));
});
```

для поиска элементов, а вызов $.each() - для обработки каждого, причем каждый - ListItem.

Чуть-чуть изменим этот код:

```
$('.sorting li').each(function(){
    if ($(this).html().test(new RegExp(term, 'ig'))) {
         // В тексте элемента списка есть то, что мы ищем,
         // значит просто помечаем этот элемент списка как выделенный
         // и идем пить пиво, потому что сегодня пятница
         $(this).addClass("light");
    }
});
```